# TypeError Django

Tags: python, django

TypeError during django project

Got this message on the error page:

TypeError at /music/1/

detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/
Exception Type:     TypeError

detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

This is my music\view.detail function

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album':album})
```

And this is a form in my detail.html which might raise the error:

```
    <form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
        <!-- forloop.counter indicates how many times the for tag has gone
        through its loop -->
        <input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song"
               value="{{ song.id }}"/>
        <label for="song{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ song.song_title }}
            {% if song.is_favorite %}
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png" />
            {% endif %}
        </label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
    </form>
```

And this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),

    # /music/<album_id>/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),

    # /music/<album_id>/favorite
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name =    
'favorite'),
]
```

Comment: What's the `urls.py` file?

Comment: I have added it above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your pattern, the parameter is called `pk` for the detail view:

```
# /music/<album_id>/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
           ^^ - this is the name of the parameter that it is looking for
```

However, your detail view has `album_id`:

```
                    vvvvvvvv - this is not matching pk
def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album':album})
```

Since those two don't match, you get the error because django cannot find a method that matches the url pattern. To fix it, make sure your pattern matches the method definition.